# New Tag Line: Pictures Before Removing Wires

Tags: feature-request

I am only half-joking with this suggestion:

Can we have a tag line on the home page of "Always Take Pictures Before Removing Wires"?

Yes, that is (a) crazy and (b) electrical specific, which isn't right because there are many other topics on this site. Plus, of course, plenty of people only come here when they have already made the mistake of disconnecting wires without taking pictures first.

A little more seriously: Could we have information in the Tour that is actually specific to the way this particular site is used. Things like:

- Take pictures before disconnecting wires
- How to post pictures
- Always list what country you are in if there is any chance (electrical, plumbing, etc.) that local building/electrical/etc. codes are involved.

Comment: The biggest drawback to this is that people won't see the message *until* after they've disconnected/disassembled/broken stuff and are desperately looking for help. No one comes here *first*.

Comment: I know! It is just so frustrating. There have been a bunch of questions recently where pictures first would have it trivial for the experts here to figure it out. But in the process I saw that the Tour is way too generic. Perhaps if it included some DIY-specific details it might help. Maybe. A little. I hope...

Comment: It is very frustrating.... an easy question made almost impossible to answer.+1